# Create and manage AWS instances via node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm try create AWS instance with Node.js api that will manage other instances and install the docker image but I can't find any docs or tutorials

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io) or [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com).

Comment: @Jens maybe this is just an opinion. For example: my opinion is that developing your own manager in node.js is much more fun than using Terraform. :)

Comment: @petrch -- the strength of terraform is that you can run a plan to see what it's doing, and leverage the output of tens of millions of dollars of investment. Your nodejs approach may be more 'fun' but this is an engineering issue and 'fun' isn't usually a good metric.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer - thanks for asking. But I am doing just fine - considering the environment where I am working - Terraform is neither the only nor the best tool available. My point was that the fact that everyone is using it does not mean the OP has to follow. I remember when Windows NT looked like a good idea and people made fun of me for using Linux and where are we now...

Answer (score 2):

#### To use the AWS SDK

First of all you should `npm install aws-sdk`.

It's a bit confusing, instance definitions are actually called "reservations". And creating one of them is called "runInstance".

So, of course you first need to initialize your EC2 object.

```
import { EC2, config } from 'aws-sdk';

config.loadFromPath(__dirname + "/../aws.config.json");
const ec2: EC2 = new EC2(); // to start/stop instances
```

Next, I personally try to use promises whenever I can when I work with the AWS instances. They clean up the code considerably.

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
```

If you already have a reservation, you can start it using its instance id.

```
const params: EC2.StartInstancesRequest = { InstanceIds: [instanceId] };
const result: EC2.StartInstancesResult = await promisify((cb) => ec2.startInstances(params, cb))();
```

And you can also stop it like that:

```
const params: EC2.StopInstancesRequest = { InstanceIds: [instanceId] };
const result: EC2.StopInstancesResult = await promisify((cb) => ec2.stopInstances(params, cb))();
```

To create your instance you need this:

```
const params: EC2.RunInstancesRequest = { InstanceType: "t1.micro", ImageId: "ami-31814f58", MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1 };
const result: EC2.Reservation = await promisify((cb) => ec2.runInstances(params, cb))();
```

And finally, to list your instances/reservations (with some optional filters):

```
const stateFilter = { Name: "instance-state-name", Values: ["running"] };
const idFilter = { Name: "instance-id", Values: [instanceId] };
const params: DescribeInstancesRequest = { Filters: [stateFilter, idFilter] };
const result: EC2.DescribeInstancesResponse = await promisify((cb) => ec2.describeInstances(params, cb))();
```

The response contains a collection of reservations, and for each reservation a collection of instances.

#### Your own images

To use your own images, you should create an "Amazon Machine Image" (AMI) in advance.

You may want to set up an "Elastic Container Registry" (ECR). You can push a docker image to this repository: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html